# Auth login is not working in laravel 5.3

Tags: laravel

I setup fresh laravel 5.3 setup. It run successfully But when I click on login button, It show  Object not found! 404 error page.

What is the problem?[image: Below is my direcctory structure]

Comment: `Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index');`

Comment: This is my route in web.php

Comment: Fresh installations don't have this issue. We'd play a guessing game trying to figure it out. If it's truly fresh, copy your `.env` file, delete the project and start over with `laravel new fcam`